# MapKit not working on device but works in simulator

Tags: iphone, frameworks, mapkit

I have added the frameworks (MapKit and CoreLocation) by selecting the Frameworks folder, right clicking, Add > Existing Frameworks.

The app builds in the Simulator (3.1.3) but fails on the Device (3.1.3) with the error:

> ld: warning: in
>   /Development/Sites/iPhone
>   Projects/SwitchViews/MapKit.framework/MapKit,
>   file is not of required architecture
>   Undefined symbols:
>   "_OBJC_CLASS_$_MKPinAnnotationView",
>   referenced from:
>         __objc_classrefs__DATA@0 in NextView.o ld: symbol(s) not found
>   collect2: ld returned 1 exit status

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It seems that I just needed to restart Xcode to get things linked up properly.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you by accident have selected the "copy to project" checkbox when adding the framework.

Try to delete the framework from your project and add it again, making sure you have selected the default framework path, and that you don't copy it to your project.

Comment: Where is this option Claus? I can't see it. I know the feature when you adding, say, an Image - but this is a different way.

Comment: Hmmm... you are probably right - this only applies to non-frameworks you add. However the "ld: warning..." indicates that it is trying to link against a local framework and not one in the SDK

Comment: the Path is System/Library/Frameworks/MapKit.framework 
the Full Path is /Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneOS3.1.3.sdk/System/Library/Frameworks/MapKit.framework 
the path type is Relative to Current SDK
is there anything wrong with that?

Comment: That sounds like the correct path. But that's not the path that's used (and reported) by the linker as you originally wrote in the question